# Function that searches for the exact same date or the closest one in the past + one extra condition

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

This is a continuation of " [Is it possible to write a VBA code that searches for the exact same data or the closest one in the past?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26230810/is-it-possible-to-write-a-vba-code-that-searches-for-the-exact-same-data-or-the#) "

Basically I would like to expand the function that @Jeeped posted but for some reason it's not going as planned eventhough I'm doing the same stuff he showed.

The extra condition in this case is that the machine used to produce the juice must be equivalent to the machine of the parameters.

[image]
(the image of what I'm doing)

Basically if a juice is made on 29/09 with machine M0 for example then I want to have the parameters that were used for that juice. Obviously the parameters of 30/09 weren't used but the parameters of 25/09 for machine M0 were used.

I edited the code @Jeeped posted in my previous question to the following

`=IFERROR(INDEX(C$2:C$10, MIN(INDEX(ROW($1:$10)+($A$2:$A$10>$F2)*1E+99+($B$2=$G$2),,))),"")`

But I get an error and I'm not sure why but I have a feeling it has to do with what I wrote ($B$2=$G$2) but how do I fix it?

DISCLAIMER: the percentages used are fictive, it's just a function I need to get working for several Workbooks that will automate some work I need to do every month.

Comment: The original had the dates in column A sorted in descending order. Now they appear scattered with no order at all. The formula provided below was designed for dates in descending order.

Comment: Added a new *array formula* approach to my post to compensate for unsorted data.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to add the condition that columns B should match G2. This should do the trick.

`=IFERROR(INDEX(C$2:C$10, MIN(INDEX(ROW($1:$9)+(($A$2:$A$10>$F2)+($B$2:$B$10<>$G2))*1E+99,,))),"")`

This type of formula does not make direct matches. It excludes everything that doesn't match and then accepts whatever is left over. So like the date in F2 is compared to the dates in column A and anything that is larger (i.e. later) is multiplied by a very large number. We do the same to the machine ID in G2. Anything that does not match the machines in column B get multiplied by the same very large number. By mathematically excluding anything that doesn't fit, we are left with what does fit.

It is also important to note that the ROW(1:9) is the *position within* C2:C10 or A2:A10, not the actual row on the worksheet.

*Addendum:* With the dates now unsorted, I can provide both a standard and an array formula to compensate. The array formula for I2 is,

```
=SUMIFS(C$2:C$10,$A$2:$A$10,MAX(IF($A$2:$A$10<=$F2,IF($B$2:$B$10=$G2,$A$2:$A$10))),$B$2:$B$10,$G2)
```

This must be finalized with Ctrl+Shift+Enter rather than simply Enter. Once entered correctly, it can be filled both right and down. Next is a standard formula that does not require Ctrl+Shift+Enter but accomplishes the same thing. Your results should resemble the following image.

```
=SUMIFS(C$2:C$10, $A$2:$A$10,MAX(INDEX(($A$2:$A$10<=$F2)*($B$2:$B$10=$G2)*($A$2:$A$10),,)),$B$2:$B$10,$G2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I tried the function just now but how come the function put the wrong value for 2 cells and everything else is correct? http://i.gyazo.com/c70242f6ec870ac5614beccbdf4fd848.png @Jeeped

Comment: @TristanDM - As expressed earlier, the dates in the original were sorted in a descending order. Now they are scattered (i.e. unsorted). I've added an array formula alternative to compensate for the unsorted data.

Answer (score 1):

I think the formula below might answer your question. Please see the image for reference.
[image: Sample output using below formula]

```
Formula Used: =INDEX($D$2:$E$7,MATCH(1,($B$2:$B$7<$H3)*($C$2:$C$7=$I3),0),1)
```

Please note - this **requires your date of parameter change to be sorted from newest to oldest**.

To apply this formula, press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER after writing the formula. This is required for excel to understand that this should function as an Array formula. On doing so, excel will automatically add the curley brackets at the beginning and end of the formula as can be seen in the image.

Only small difference for formula to get %Oranges will be replacing the last 1 by 2.

```
INDEX($D$2:$E$7,MATCH(1,($B$2:$B$7<$H3)*($C$2:$C$7=$I3),0),2)
```

Hope this answers your question. Please let me know if you need further assistance.